# Calculus exponential function/ slope and equtation

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Consider the function $f(x) = 3(1 − e^x)$. Use exact values when answering the following questions:

1. Find the slope of the graph of $f(x)$ at the point where it crosses the $x$-axis.
2. Find the equations of the lines tangent and the perpendicular to $f(x)$ at this point.

My attempt was:
$$
0= 3(1-e^x) \\
0= 3-3e^x \\
3e^x=3 \\ 
e^x=1 \\
\ln(e^x)= \ln (1) \\
x=0
$$
but the answer was wrong -.-

Comment: That tells you where the graph of $f$ crosses the $x$-axis, but you want the *slope* of the graph there.

Comment: @user61527 I still did not get it

Comment: My point was that you had gotten the first step, but didn't *use* it yet. Do you know how to find the slope of a function with calculus?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have successfully found at what $x$ we have $f(x) = 0$, but the first question asks for the slope at this $x$.

**Hint 1:**
What calculus oriented idea gives us the slope of a line at a point?

**Hint 2:**
Now we have a point and a slope, how can we find the line given these conditions? What relation do we know about a line and the line perpendicular to it?

Comment: Wouldn't the slope be zero also? when I take the derivative of any number will be zero. (Am I going in the wrong direction :/?)

Comment: @John you need to take the derivative of $f(x)$ before evaluating it at some $x$. Another way to say this is we're trying to find $f'(0)$, but that would require that we know the formula for $f'(x)$ first.